# I need a faster solution for the following problem

Tags: c++, algorithm

You are given `N` pairs of numbers `n`, `k`. For each pair, calculate the number of divisors of the `P`.

```
P = k^n * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k)
```

From `nr_div_huge.in` is read `N`, and then are read `N` pairs of `n and k`. In the output file `nr_div_huge.out` is written on each line, the numbers of divisors of P for each pair. Because it can be huge, it will be displayed modulo 1.000.000.007.

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 15.000
- 1 ≤ k, n ≤ 1.000.000.000
- Memory limit: 0.1MB
- Time limit: 0.2s

Example:

`nr_div_huge.in`

```
2
2 3
4 4
```

`nr_div_huge.out`

```
8
20
```

Explication:

For the first pair P=54 and 54 have 8 divisors.
The second pair P=2560 and 2560 have 20 divisors.

That is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define MOD 1000000007
using namespace std;

ifstream fin ("nr_div_huge.in");
ofstream fout("nr_div_huge.out");

bool sieve[30000];
long long int prime[3000];
int N, k, n, r, P;

//making the Sieve of Eratosthenes have in the `prime` array the prime numbers up to 30000
void Erat()
{
    int r=0;
    sieve[0]=sieve[1]=1;

    for(int i=2; i*i<=30000; i++)
        if(sieve[i]==0)
            for(int j=2; j<=30000/i; j++)sieve[i*j]=1;

    for(int i=1; i<=30000; ++i)
        if(!sieve[i])prime[++r]=i;
}

//finding the numbers of divisors with Euler formula
int divisors(unsigned int n, unsigned int power)
{
    int r=0, d, p, nr=1;
    d=prime[++r];

    while(n>1)
    {
        p=0;
        while(n%d==0)
        {
            p++;
            n/=d;
        }

        if(d==2 && p>0)
            nr=(1LL*nr*(p*power))%MOD;
        else if(p>0)
            nr=(1LL*nr*(p*power+1))%MOD;

        if(prime[r+1]==0)d++;
        else d=prime[++r];

        if(d*d>n)d=n;
    }

    return nr;
}
/*
    I've transformed the formula P = k^n * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... +k) into P= k^(n+1)*(k+1)/2

    Also, I've used this property:
        If we have 2 numbers a and b, which are co-prime numbers, a will have n divisors and b m divisors,
        the (a*b) number will have m*n divisors.

*/
int NrP(long long int n, long long int k)
{
    unsigned long long int power=1,nrdk1,nrdkn,res=0;

    nrdk1=divisors(k+1,1);
    nrdkn=divisors(k,n+1);
    res=(1LL*nrdk1*nrdkn)%MOD;
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    Erat();
    fin>>N;

    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++)
    {
        fin>>n>>k;
        fout<<NrP(n,k)<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Algorithm Description:

I make the sieve of Eratosthenes in the beginning, to have the prime numbers up to 30000 in the `prime` array. To be more faster, to calculate `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k` sum, I use the formula `(k*(k+1))/2` and the `P` becomes `(k^(n+1) * (k+1))/2`. As `k` and `k+1` are co-prime, then `k^(n+1)` and `k+1` will be co-prime too, and one of them will be even. To eliminate `/2`, I divide the even number. Because the numbers are co-primes, the number of divisors is `n*m`, where `n` is the number of divisors of `k^(n+1)` and `m` is the number of divisors of `k+1`.

To calculate the numbers of divisors, I used Euler's formula:

```
n = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * … * pk^ek - prime factorization

number of divisors = (e1 + 1) * (e2 + 1) * ... * (ek + 1)
```

How can I speed up the solution? Or is there any faster solution?

Comment: "Are given N pairs of numbers n k. For each pair, calculate the number of divisors of the next number." can you please post an example with 2 small numbers?

Comment: Can you add a plain-english description of your algorithm?  I don't quite understand what's going on.  If you are literally computing the value of `k^n`, the resulting number will have 10^9 decimal digits, and will definitely not fit in a long long.

Answer (score 1):

prime factorize `k`.  Let's say that `k` is `2*2*2*3*5 = 120`.
So any divisor of `k` must be `2^x * 3^y * 5^z` where `x`,`y`,`z` can be `[0,1,2]`, `[0,1]`, `[0,1]` individually.
Likewise, the divisors of `k^n` must be same form `2^x*3^y*5^z`, where `x`,`y`,`z` can be `[0,1 .. 3*n]`, `[0, .. n]`, `[0, .. n]` individually. 
The number of unique combinations you can form with these elements, then, is the product of all of the choices: `(3*n+1)*(n+1)*(n+1)`

(if that's not clear, consider the analogy of counting the number of unique combinations of ice cream sundaes where an ice cream sundae is made of 1 of 3 possible ice cream flavors and 1 of 4 possible ice cream toppings... the total number of unique sundaes is then 3*4.  Here, our choices are how many `2`s to use, how many `3`s to use, and how many `5`s to use.  Each unique combination produces a unique product.)

Also add the prime factors of `(k * (k+1)) / 2` to the prime factor counts and it should work.

Edit: I see that your proposed solution is already using Euler's function (`n = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * … * pk^ek - prime factorization`).

The solution outlined here uses that as well, but the missing insight is that the prime factorization of `k^2` is very easily derivable from the prime factorization of `k`: the prime factorization of `12` is `2^2 * 3`, and the prime factoriation of `12*12 = 144` is `2^2 * 3 * 2^2 * 3 = 2^4 * 3^2`.  Because of this, you DON'T need to calculate `k^n`.  You merely need to prime factorize `k`, and then use this data to derive the prime factorization of `k^n`.

== Edit 2 ==
You still have errors after that, so maybe some of your computed values which are `int`s need to be `long long`s? Also, I see your sieve goes up to 3000, but shouldn't it go up to sqrt(10^9)?

Comment: how fast is prime decomposition?

Comment: If you already have a sieve that stores the lowest prime factor of each number, then you just continue dividing `k` by its lowest prime factor until the result is prime, so it's `O(number of prime factors of k)`, which I think is around `log(k)` (specifically it's [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182325/how-does-one-know-the-growth-rate-of-distinct-prime-divisors)).  To make the sieve itself is `O(sqrt(k))`, so that dominates the runtime.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. My algorithm is correct, but is not that fast how it should be.

Comment: how do you know it's not fast enough?

Comment: Is not fast enough or is not correct, or I have a mistake in my code. I am using a site with questions and I have just 5/100 points.

Comment: have you tried testing it, maybe locally, with large n and k? As I pointed out in the comments, it looks like your code is attempting to produce the value `k^n` in a variable, which will not work because that value is huge.  I'll update my answer to make the missing insight more clear.

Comment: If I will store the number in an array, I will exceed the memory limit and I won't be able to count the divisors.

Comment: "If I will store the number in an array, I will exceed the memory limit and I won't be able to count the divisors." What do you mean by this?  Which number will be stored in an array, and why? Did you try testing with n=10^9 and k=10^9 locally?  Also I added an explanation to this answer that explains what's missing from the solution you have.

Comment: Ok, I have understood. I will try!

Comment: Now I have 20 points. The rest of test are with "Wrong answer".

Comment: unfortunate.  Which site is this on? Can you view the testcases which failed?  I edited the answer with some more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You must do a little mathematics first to make the problem simpler. If you do not, you will end computing numbers that will not feet in a `long long` variable, requiring a multi precision library like gmp and taking too much time.

But once you observe that 1+2+...+k is just k*(k+1)/2, you end with:

```
P = k^(n+1) * (k+1) / 2
```

while `k` and `k+1` are co-primes (trivial property of successive integers). Then, you just decompose `k` and `k+1` in prime factors. One of them is divisible by 2. But this gives you **without even computing `P`** its prime factors decomposition.

From there, you have `P = a0^b0 * ... * ax^bx` and the number of divisors is `(b0+1)*...*(bx+1)`.

Application on your examples:

- 2,3: P = 3^3 * 4 / 2 = 2^1*3^3 - number of divisors 2 * 4 = 8
- 4,4: P = 4^5 * 5 / 2 = 5 * (2^2)^5 / 2 = 2^9 * 5^1 - number of divisors 10 * 2 = 20

You still have to code the algorithm in C++, but it will be much more efficient than huge numbers operations.

---

Here is a possible C++ implementation

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// Will search all primes up to (SQSIZE * SQSIZE) - 1
constexpr const unsigned long SQSIZE = 200;

std::vector<unsigned> make_sieve(unsigned sqsize) {
    unsigned size = sqsize * sqsize;
    std::vector<unsigned> sieve(size, 0);
    // Classic Eratosthene
    for (unsigned i=2; i<sqsize; i++) {
        if(sieve[i] == 0) {
            for(unsigned j = i*i; j<size; j+=i) {
                sieve[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    unsigned len=0;
    // Pack prime number in the vector
    for (unsigned i=2; i<size; i++) {
        if (sieve[i] == 0) sieve[len++] = i;
    }
    sieve.resize(len);
    return sieve;
}

unsigned long n_divisors(unsigned long k, unsigned long n, const std::vector<unsigned> &sieve) {
    unsigned long n_div = 1;
    for(unsigned i: sieve) {
        unsigned exp = 0;
        while ((k % i) == 0) {
            exp += 1;
            k /= i;
        }
        // special processing if k divisible by 2: use k^n/2
        if ((i == 2) && (exp != 0)) n_div *= (exp * n - 1) + 1;
        else n_div *= exp * n + 1;
        if (k == 1) break;
    }
    if (n_div == 1) n_div = 2;  // k is prime and greater sieve max
    return n_div;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> sieve = make_sieve(SQSIZE);
    unsigned long k, n, n_div;
    unsigned N;

    std::ifstream fin ("nr_div_huge.in");
    std::ofstream fout("nr_div_huge.out");

    fin >> N;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<N; i++) {
        fin >> n >> k;
        n_div = n_divisors(k, n+1, sieve) * n_divisors(k + 1, 1, sieve);
        fout << n_div << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No need for `long long` here.  `n` and `k` are less than 1000000000 and fit in a 32 bits integer. So `unsigned long` is used.

Beware: above code blindy assumes no IO problems and never tests them. Never do that for production grade code...